# Selenoid: What does the count attribute do in a quota file?

Tags: selenium, selenoid

I started Selenoid with docker: `aerokube/cm:latest selenoid start --args "-limit 20"`

I then created a quota file with:

`user.xml`:

```
<qa:browsers xmlns:qa="urn:config.gridrouter.qatools.ru">
<browser name="chrome" defaultVersion="62.0">
    <version number="62.0">
        <region name="1">
            <host name="1.2.3.4" port="4445" count="10"/>
        </region>
    </version>
</browser>
</qa:browsers>
```

When I run with this user it runs 20 in parallel. I thought `count="10"` would mean this user can do at most 10 in parallel. And `-limit 20` was the max for the VM. Is this the correct usage of `count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact `count` field in [Ggr](https://github.com/aerokube/ggr/) [quota XML file](http://aerokube.com/ggr/latest/#_creating_quota_files) means **host weight**. It makes sense when two or more hosts are present in quota. This attribute is called so for historical reasons. So when you have e.g. two hosts in quota with counts `1` and `3` then sessions will be distributed as `1:3` over these hosts. When counts are equal then distribution should be random uniform. If you set `count` equal to the real count of browsers for each host - then you also get **random uniform distribution**. This is what we are recommend to do in production.